# Visual studio: How to search for text in a sub folder of a solution

Tags: visual-studio

I wish to find all occurrences of a certain code in a sub-folder of a solution.

For example, find all "return 0" in folder X.

So far I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> which search anywhere in the solution which isn't good for my propose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Find in files" (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), then look in: "Entire solution" or specify the folder path.